# Angular doesn't load a module - $injector:modulerr

Tags: angularjs, angular-module

I get the following error in my application:

[image: error]

The problem only appears when loading a specific module, here's my main module:

**app.module.js**

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module( 'app', [
            /*
             * Shared modules
             */
            'app.layout',
            'app.core',
            /*
             * Feature areas
             */
            'app.users',
            'app.purchases'//This is the module that generates the modulerr error
        ] )
        .config( [ '$locationProvider', hashbagRemove ] );


    function hashbagRemove( $locationProvider ) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode( true );

    }

})();
```

This is the module that generates the error:

**purchases.module.js**

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular.module( 'app.purchases', [
        'app.purchases.suppliers'
    ] );

})();
```

**suppliers.module.js**

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular.module( 'app.purchases.suppliers', [] );

})();
```

As you can see i've got a modular application, the thing is that if i load that module the application crashes, i already checked all the controllers and factories to see if there was any mistake there, and all of them are correct, also i already verified that i was loading all the necesary scripts, i don't get why the error persists.

To give you a clearer idea of the structure of my application here's a pic of it:[image: tree]

And here's **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SOS Control</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./components/bootstrap/bootstrap-3.1.1.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./components/font-awesome/font-awesome-4.4.0.min.css"/>
    <base href="/"/>
</head>
<body>

    <div ui-view></div>

<!--==================================================== SCRIPTS ====================================================-->

    <!----------------------------------------------Other-->
    <!--<script src="./components/lodash/lodash-3.10.1.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="./components/underscore/underscore-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

    <!---------------------------------------------JQuery-->
    <script src="./components/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

    <!--------------------------------------------Angular-->
    <script src="./components/angular/angular-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./components/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-0.13.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./components/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router-0.2.15.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./components/restangular/restangular-1.5.1.min.js"></script>

    <!---------------------------------------Main Modules-->
    <script src="./app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="./modules/core/core.module.js"></script>
    <script src="./modules/layout/layout.module.js"></script>

    <!---------------------------------------Users Module-->
    <script src="./modules/users/users.module.js"></script>
    <script src="./modules/users/users.routes.js"></script>
    <script src="./modules/users/signin/signin.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="./modules/users/signout/signout.factory.js"></script>

    <script src="./modules/users/account/account.module.js"></script>
    <script src="./modules/users/account/account.routes.js"></script>
    <script src="./modules/users/account/edit-data/edit-data.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="./modules/users/account/reset-password/reset-password.controller.js"></script>

    <!-----------------------------------Purchases Module-->
    <script src="./modules/purchases/purchases.module.js"></script>
    <script src="./modules/purchases/purchases.routes.js"></script>

    <script src="./modules/purchases/suppliers/suppliers.module.js"></script>
    <script src="./modules/purchases/suppliers/suppliers.routes.js"></script>
    <script src="./modules/purchases/suppliers/suppliers-dashboard.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="./modules/purchases/suppliers/create-supplier/create-supplier.factory.js"></script>
    <script src="./modules/purchases/suppliers/create-supplier/create-supplier.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="./modules/purchases/suppliers/read-supplier/read-supplier.factory.js"></script>
    <script src="./modules/purchases/suppliers/read-supplier/read-supplier.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="./modules/purchases/suppliers/update-supplier/update-supplier.factory.js"></script>
    <script src="./modules/purchases/suppliers/update-supplier/update-supplier.controller.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

### UPDATE 1

With the updated error (using the dev. version of angular) it seems like the error is generated from this file:

**suppliers.routes.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module( 'app.purchases.suppliers' )

        // Collect the ui-route states
        .constant( 'states', getRouteStates() )

        // Configure the ui-route states and state resolvers
        .config( [ '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'states', stateConfigurator ] );

    function stateConfigurator( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, states ) {

        states.forEach( function ( state ) {

            $stateProvider.state( state.name, state.config );

        } );

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise( "/" );

    }

    // Define the ui-route states
    function getRouteStates() {
        return [
            {
                name: 'suppliersDashboard',
                config: {
                    url: '/compras/proveedores',
                    templateUrl: './modules/purchases/suppliers/suppliers-dashboard.view.html',
                    title: 'Menu Principal de Proveedores',
                    controller: 'SuppliersDashboardController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'createSupplier',
                config: {
                    url: '/compras/proveedores/nuevo',
                    templateUrl: './modules/purchases/suppliers/create-supplier/create-supplier.view.html',
                    title: 'Nuevo Proveedor',
                    controller: 'CreateSupplierController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'listSupplier',
                config: {
                    url: '/compras/proveedores/listado',
                    templateUrl: './modules/purchases/suppliers/read-supplier/list-supplier.view.html',
                    title: 'Listado de Proveedores',
                    controller: 'ReadSupplierController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'detailSupplier',
                config: {
                    url: '/compras/proveedores/:supplierId/:supplierName',
                    templateUrl: './modules/purchases/suppliers/read-supplier/detail-supplier.view.html',
                    title: 'Detalles del Proveedor',
                    controller: 'ReadSupplierController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'updateSupplier',
                config: {
                    url: '/compras/proveedores/:supplierId/:supplierName/editar',
                    templateUrl: './modules/purchases/suppliers/update-supplier/update-supplier.view.html',
                    title: 'Editar Proveedor',
                    controller: 'UpdateSupplierController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            }
        ];
    }

})();
```

What i do is that i create a constant in each module called `states` where i store the states properties (i'm using ui-router), then in the `module.config` i iterate over the constant states to add the states to the `$stateProvider`.

Something that i think that might be causing the trouble is that in every module i declare the same constant, `states`, can't two different modules have constants with the same name?

Comment: So something is wrong with `app.purchases` dependency module `app.purchases.suppliers`. Is it defined, can you show the definition of that module too?

Comment: Use development version of angular to get more verbose error and stack trace output. Then update question with what error actually says

Comment: @charlietfl Could you please tell me where do i get the dev version, i cant find it...

Comment: @l0lander yes, `app.purchases.suppliers` is declared and loaded

Comment: @l0lander just added the declaration of `app.purchases.suppliers` module to the post

Comment: it's the version that doesn't have `.min` in it... there is more robust error reporting in it

Comment: @charlietfl done, check out the first image of the error again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that i declared an empty json array at **purchases.routes.js**:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('app.purchases')

    // Collect the ui-route states
    .constant('states', getRouteStates())

    // Configure the ui-route states and state resolvers
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'states', stateConfigurator]);

function stateConfigurator($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, states) {

    states.forEach(function (state) {

        $stateProvider.state(state.name, state.config);

    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

}

// Define the ui-route states
function getRouteStates() {
    return [
        {}//THIS WAS THE ERROR
    ];
}

})();
```

When iterating through the `states` constant that array didn't have any property, so that it couldn't find `state.name`and `state.config`.

Thanks [@charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) i could solve this when i saw the complete error when using development version of Angular.

Answer (score 1):

I see you're using **Module pattern** and that's good.

The bad thing is, that at the moment of `app.purchases` module invocation which is the very moment after the script gets compiled (loaded from `index.html`) the `app.purchases.suppliers` is not compiled.

**Solution:** Order is important here as those scripts get executed in order you reference them in `index.html`.

- Move the `<script>...</script>` element which references `app.purchases.suppliers` module definition above the one that references the `app.purchases` module.
- Make sure that units (services, controllers, directives...) linked to their module come right after the file that contains their linked module definition.
- At the end reference the main module file that uses all those other modules, and after that it's own units (services, controllers, directives, configs...)
- Follow this rule also for dependencies within a module itself (if a controller is using some service, make sure the service is referenced above the controller)

**Advice:** Always reference first - the files containing units which are not depending on other units. To stop worrying about this you might consider using `requireJS`

Comment: This definitly don't work, i did what you said, and now it throws lots of error of `$injector:nomod`

Comment: Also, how could i use react.js with my structure?

Comment: It's `requirejs`. However i'm sure the problem is here, if the number of error changes, it means you're on the way to figure out the correct order, just follow the rules i wrote above ;)

Comment: Oh, sorry jaja, `require.js` seems nice, could you please update your answer with an example of using it?

Comment: I already solved the problem, but you points seems to be logic, the one that i dont understand is `Make sure that units (services, controllers, directives...) linked to their module come right after the file that contains their linked module definition.` what does it mean? for example if i have module **x** and a submodule **xx** and a service **xxservice** in what order should i load them?

Comment: That just meant: First the module definition file, then the other files which belong to that module so you wouldn't end up with module not being defined in the moment of referencing it to say... define a service or controller etc